# opencv display video as concave image

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I use the next code to display video from my camera:

```
VideoCapture cap(1);
if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
{
    return;
}

Mat edges;
namedWindow("Video", 1);
for (;;)
{

    //set the callback function for any mouse event
    setMouseCallback("Video", CallBackFunction, NULL);

    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera

    imshow("Video", frame);
    //if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    waitKey(DELAY_TIME);
}
```

But, I want that the video image will display as a concave/convex image. Is there a quick and easy way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What are concave/convex images?

Comment: Like the picture here: 
http://alltelleringet.deviantart.com/art/concave-convex-186367734

Answer (score 0):

You can apply barrel-like distortion to your frame with [remap function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap).
[Small tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html).